# Vim Editor is very smart?

Tags: vim, text-editors

I am programming in C++ or Java. I want to use the Vim editor, and have heard that I can configure the Vim editor to be able to go:

1. From an object to the definition
2. From a function to the definition
3. From a class name to the definition

Do we have any professional Vim-er that could tell me how exactly to configure Vim for that?

Comment: Multiposting is encouraged for questions that may be relevant to both areas, since different audiences can provide different input.

Comment: @Narek you should ask programming related questions on http://stackoverflow.com, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks

Comment: @Nick it isn't really programming, it's how to configure the editor.

Comment: @Diago, care to comment on that in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/allow-cross-posting-of-questions-to-more-than-one-so-site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're referring to is tags I believe. Check [here](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/usr_29.html) for section 29.1 - using tags.

Comment: correct, tags:

  http://vim.runpaint.org/navigation/navigating-tags/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the "code complete" plugin:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1764
- http://files.myopera.com/mbbill/files/code_complete.gif

---

**Update**:
Sorry I misunderstood your question, I think you are looking for [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) (and maybe [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)), 
I use ctags all the time but it works best for c, but I found it quite usable even for java.

I don't have a good tutorial right now but if you [google for words like vim ctags tutorial](http://www.google.se/search?q=vim+ctags+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) you will find some usable links... (I hope anyway)

I also found this, that will create a index of all the java files under the src dir, 
for both ctags and cscope

```
ctags -R src/ & find src/ -name '*.java' > cscope.files &&  cscope -b
```

It work really nice under Linux, but if you are sitting on windows this also works under cygwin.

---

That was one really confusing answer... but maybe it could be usable anyway :)

Comment: thats not what the question was about, its not about insertin something at the current position, it is about navigating to the place where it is declared / defined